# Could someone help me understand this Sieve of Eratosthenes script? The last couple lines have me stumped

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

All right, so I get the principle behind the Sieve of Eratosthenes. I tried, and largely failed, to write one myself (I wrote a functional prime number generator, it just wasn't efficient or a sieve). I think I'm more having an issue understanding the math, but the programming has me mixed up too.

```
import numpy as np

def primesfrom2to(n):
    sieve = np.ones(n/3 + (n%6==2), dtype=np.bool) 
    # print(sieve) for n = 10 returns [True, True, True]
```

Ok, write off the bat I'm a little confused. It's generating a list of truth values that will progressively be marked false as they are determined to be composite. I think it's saying no more than 1/3 of the values less than n will be prime, but what does adding a modolus operation achieve?

```
    sieve[0] = False
```

marks 1 as false?

```
    for i in range(int(n**0.5)//3+1):
        # print(i) for n = 10 returns 0 and 1 on separate lines
```

This is setting the range to check. No number has a product greater than its square root. Whats up with the dividing by `3+1`?

```
        if sieve[i]:
            k=3*i+1|1
            #print(k) for n = 10 returns '5' doesn't change till it adds 7 at n = 50
```

Ok so, if `sieve[i]`is true (so prime / not yet marked as composite?) then `3*i + 1 or 1`? How does this work exactly? It seems to be generating primes that it will be multiplied later to remove all the subsequent products, but I don't know how.

```
            sieve[      ((k*k)/3)      ::2*k] = False
            sieve[(k*k+4*k-2*k*(i&1))/3::2*k] = False
```

ok so both of these are taking the primes `k` and marking all further multiples of them? if `n=5` wouldn't that make it `sieve[8.33::10] = False`? And the other one like `sieve[41.3::10]`? I just don't get it.

```
print(np.r_[2,3,((3*np.nonzero(sieve)[0]+1)|1)])
```

All right, and finally actually generating the list of primes. Again, what's up with multiplying it by three? Obviously there is something fundamental about 3 in this code that I just don't get. Also I'm failing to grasp the `|1` concept again.

Oh and just for fun here's my effective and horribly inefficient attempt.

```
import numpy
def sieve(num):

    master = numpy.array([i for i in range(2, num+1)])
    run = []
    y=2


    while y <= ((num+1)**(1/2)): 
        thing = [x for x in range(y, num+1, y) if x > 5 or x == 4]
        run = run + thing
        y = y+1 
    alist = numpy.in1d(master, run, invert = True)
    blist = (master[alist])
    print(blist)
```

It took 57s to calculate the primes up to 500,000. I was doing the Euler sum of primes up to 2,000,000 problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple sieve algorithm in numpy:

```
import numpy as np
def sieve(Nmax):
    """Calculate prime numbers between 0 and Nmax-1."""
    is_prime = np.ones(Nmax, dtype=bool)
    Pmax = int(np.sqrt(Nmax)+1)
    is_prime[0] = is_prime[1] = False
    p = 2
    dp = 1
    while p <= Pmax:
        if is_prime[p]:
            is_prime[p*2::p] = False
        p += dp
        dp = 2
    primes = np.argwhere(is_prime)[:,0]
    print(primes)

sieve(100)
```

If I remove the print statement, it runs for Nmax=10^8 in 2.5 seconds on my modest laptop.

This algorithm is a bit inefficient because it needs to store the prime-ness of even values and multiples of 3. You can save on storage space by filtering out those, so that you keep track of the prime-ness of n*6+1 and n*6+5, for any integer n>=1. That saves you two thirds of the storage space, at the expense of a bit more book-keeping. It seems that you attempted to start with the difficult version. Moreover, all the bookkeeping tends to become expensive if it involves the Python interpreter evaluating `if` statements and doing the memory management of your lists. Python/numpy's array slicing is a much more natural way to do it, and it's probably fast enough for your purposes.

Regarding your questions:

- (n%6==2) is boolean, will be interpreted as 0 or 1 and will add one more element to prevent an "off-by-one" error.
- `int(n**0.5)//3+1` should be read as `int(int(n**0.5)/3) + 1`. Division goes before addition. The division by three is so that you only allocate space for 6n+1 and 6n+5 values.
- `k=3*i+1|1` means `k=3*i+1`, add one if it is even (it is a bit-wise or). Array element 'i' corresponds to potential prime number `(3*i+1)|1`. So if the array indices are `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]`, they represent the numbers `[1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, ...]`.
- Setting the sieve elements to False is done separately for the elements representing 6n+1 and 6n+5, that's why there are two assignments.
- If you're running this in Python 2.7, integer division is always truncated, so 9/2 will result in 4. In Python 3, it would be better to use the // operator for integer divisions, i.e. `(k*k)/3` should be `(k*k)//3`.

Edit: you may wish to attribute the algorithm that you were asking about: [Fastest way to list all primes below N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n/3035188#3035188).

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot more sense. The bitwise or had me especially confused. Expressing it as 6n+1 and 6n+5 made it click. I had learned about proving there are infinite primes in logic and these were definitely alluded to.

Oh, and that link is where I got this code from!